# Using getters with this. in java

Tags: java, oop, getter

I am doing a project for CS, and I just realized that I do not understand the mechanics behind the this. java reference and getters. Specifically, if I have the following:

```
class Circle{
   private int radius;
}

public Circle(int radius){
   this.radius = radius;
}

public int getRadius(){
   return radius;
}
```

- Why is it that for the constructor, I use `this.radius` to reference the data field "radius" in the Circle class, but for the constructor, I have `this.radius = radius`?
- Does it make a difference whether or not I use the this. so long as it is the only data field named `radius`?
- I just tested it on Sublime, and it outputs the same result.
  Just according to my own logic, would it not make more sense to use `this.radius` to return the radius in the `getRadius()` getter instead of just `return radius` because I am referring to the data field in the object `Circle`?

I really appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: As your constructor `public Circle(int radius){...}`  has parameter name `radius` which is same like the global parameter name, and you are assigning global parameter(`radius`) to local parameter (`radius`) and as there is an ambiguity in names. To simplify we refer Global parameter with *this*. Like *this.radius = radius*

Answer (score 3):

It's because `radius` is the name of both parameter of constructor and field of the class. To disambiguate those `this` keyword is used. In case of getter `this` is not needed, but also won't hurt. Some formatters add `this` by default, it's equivalent to:

```
public int getRadius(){
    return this.radius;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `this` in the constructor if you do not ***shadow*** the local name. That is with

```
public Circle(int r){
    this.radius = r;
}
```

You **can** write

```
public Circle(int r){
    radius = r;
}
```

The `this` is only **required** when it is used to specify which `radius` you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you refer to `this.radius` that means you use a class field variable. Otherwise (in your code) you may re-assign your `radius` as an argument in a given constructor that is may be unwanted in your case. To distinguish it you must either use different name of a variable or use `this`.